# Key based cache expiration with Mongoid embedded documents

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, caching, mongoid

How would you set up a Russian doll like key based cache expiration with embedded documents?
As described by [37 signals](http://37signals.com/svn/posts/3112-how-basecamp-next-got-to-be-so-damn-fast-without-using-much-client-side-ui)

I believe `touch` was added for `belongs_to` in Mongoid 3.0 but how would you deal with it for embedded documents?

Example classes:

```
class House
  embeds_many :persons
end

class Person
  embedded_in :house
end
```

View:

```
<% cache ['v1', house] do %>
  <%= house.some_attribute %>
  <% house.persons.each |person| %>
    <% cache ['v1' person] do %> 
      <%= render 'houses/person', person: person %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

What would be the simplest way to generalize the touching? So that when I update a person, the house it's embedded in gets touched.

EDIT: Or maybe the thinking here is that it's relatively cheap to re-render all the embedded items? Of course I could just do this:

```
class Person
  after_save :touch_house
  def touch_house
    house.touch
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I implement daisy chaining of embedded touching with observers.

```
class PersonObserver < Mongoid::Observer
  def sweep(person)
    person.house.touch
  end

  alias_method :after_update, :sweep
  alias_method :after_create, :sweep
end
```

When you update or create a person, it touches that person's house effectively updating the houses' update_at time stamp.

In order to use observers, add this to your application.rb:

```
config.mongoid.observers = :person_observer
```

Comment: Thanks! the only problem is that this gets kind of messy with a depth of > 3 embedded documents.

Answer (score 0):

I define this concern:

```
module ParentTouchable

  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  def touch_parent
    self._parent.touch
  end

end
```

and then I include it in the embedded model, so I can call touch_parent in an after_save callback. Let's say my embedded model is Comment:

```
class Comment

  include Mongoid::Document
  include ParentTouchable

  after_save :touch_parent

end
```